Order of execution in try except finally
I never really use finally, so I wanted to test a few things before using it more regularly. I noticed that when running:
def f():
    try:
        1/0
        # 1/1
    except:
        print('except')      # 1
        raise                # 2
    finally:
        print('finally')     # 3

try:
    f()
except:
    print("haha")

we get this order of execution:
except
finally
haha

What is the rule for the order of excution?
From what I see I get this rule:

run everything in the except block, but not the raise statement, if any such statement is present
run the finally block
go back to the except block, and run the last raise statement, if present

Is that correct?
Are there other statements than raise in an except block that can be postponed after the finally block?

Clearer with this example:
def f():
    try:
        1/0
        # 1/1
    except:
        print('except')    #1
        raise print("a")   #2  # nonsense but just to see in which order this line is executed         
    finally:
        print('finally')   #3

which gives
except
a
finally
foo


it tries, it then excepts, and then finally, finally is always called even if the try doesnt error

Were you expecting something different?

I know this @ReeceHarris but here the full except block is not run completely : the last statement of the except block is not run. Then the finally block is run, and then back to the end of the except block.

@SIGHUP I don't know, but I just want to find a fixed set of rules that I keep in my head for a more confident everyday use of finally. Do you confirm 1) run "except" block, but not the raise statement if any, 2) run "finally" block  3) do the rest of the "except" block. Is that correct? Are there other statements in the "except" block that can be postponed after the finally?

@Basj the raise in the except block is used by the outer try so for example a nested try inside a try. if you get me, thats why it prints "haha"

ZeroDivisionError is "caught" and you print 'except'. You then raise that exception to the function's caller. But, before the function terminates, the finally block will run. f() exits and the exception is then observed in the main program. Hence the order of output that you see

According to [Python.Docs]: Errors and Exceptions - Defining Clean-up Actions (emphasis is mine, read all the bullets though):


...
An exception could occur during execution of an except or else clause. Again, the exception is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.
...


So that's the expected behavior.
